# gsub error extract url with R, what did i miss

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I tried to extract URL but everytime I run my code. It didn't work. What did miss? any help will be great.

> x$URL <- gsub("(.*)(http://www.bloomin.com)(.*jpg)(.*)",
>                 "//2//3", x$Product.Description.)

[1] //2//3

It was what I return. I want to get http://www.blooming.com/image/xxxxxxxx.jpg in return from below vector.

```
<div>Colorful Floor chair Series</div><div><br /></div><div>Soft
Suede</div><div><br /></div><div>Cute bubble design</div><div><br
/></div><div><p align="center"><p align="center"><img
src="http://gdetail.image-gemkt.com/186/716088198/2010/2/e3b117e2-a7bd-4d.GIF"
/></div><div><p align="center"><p align="center"><img
src="http://www.blooming.com/image/xxxxxxxx.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: uh oh. regex with html? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Not really the same case: this is about matching URLs inside HTML, not about matching HTML tags (for which the linked response is appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

1. Backreferences must be refered by backslash no forward slash.
2. Use `.*?` (*non-greedy*) to match all the characters which exists inbetween `.com` and the file extension `.jpg`

   ```
   x$URL <- gsub("(?s).*\\b(http://www\\.blooming\\.com\\b.*?\\.jpg\\b).*",
                                 "\\1", x$Product.Description.)
   ```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cE6fE6/1)

Comment: You saved me! Thanks a lot